# ListBox GetSelectedIndices Count vs Length

Tags: c#, count, listbox, variable-length

In my web application, I created a ListBox that is populated with a list of items.  I have been doing some research and discovered that I can count the number of selected items with the code below in my IF statement.

Using C#, aspx

```
If (ListBox1.GetSelectedIndices().Count() > 0) {
//do something
}
else { //do something else
}
```

I have also discovered another property called Length, which seems to do the same exact thing.

```
If (ListBox1.GetSelectedIndices().Length > 0) {
//do something
}
else { //do something else
}
```

Is there any difference between the 2?  Both seem to satisfy my condition in how I am use it, but not sure if 1 way is better/faster than the other, etc..  Any input is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `ListBox` inherits or implements `Enumerable` that has an option to return `Count` the number of elements in the list.

The `ListBox` also has it own method called `.Length` which has a similar effects but specifically used in the class `ListBox`

If I would have to choose between two I would go with `Lenght`

Answer (score 0):

`Count()` is an extension method added from the `System.Linq` namespace, and is - generally speaking - much slower than the `Length` property for types that have it, because it has to enumerate the entire collection first. It's ideal to use `Length` when you can. `GetSelectedIndecies()` just returns an array in ASPX, so the `Count()` method is quite unnecessary in this instance.